# How to merge 2 dictionaries on id and write them to an xml file

Tags: python, xml

I have product information in to different objects, product description and product highlights. both of these objects have product_id, so I can associate them together.

`decription_items` is a list of dictionary, e.g:

```
[
 {'product_id': '123', 'description': 'desc1', 'price': '$40' },
 {'product_id': '124', 'description': 'desc2', 'price': '$50' },
 {'product_id': '125', 'description': 'desc3', 'price': '$99' },
]
```

`product_highlight_dict` is a dictionary of (product_id, `ProductHighlight`)

```
{
 '123': <product_123_highligh>,
 '124': <product_124_highligh>,
 '125': <product_125_highligh>,
}
```

and finally `ProductHighlight` is a class:

```
class ProductHighlight:
    def __init__(self, product_id, location, area):
        self.product_id = product_id
        self.location = location
        self.area = area
```

What I want to do is to merge these two types and write them to an xml document, in the following code, I can merge the two types:

```
for description_item in self.decription_items:
    product_id = .get('product_id')
        if product_id:
            product_highlight = spider.product_highlight_dict.get(product_id)
            # I don't know how to combine description_item and 
            # product_highlight and write them to an xml
```

### Update

I use the following code to write `product_highlight_dict` to an xml. I don't know how to include `description_item` in the following logic?

```
    highlights = []
    for k in self.product_highlight_dict:
        highlights.append(vars(self.product_highlight_dict[k]))

    xml = dicttoxml.dicttoxml(highlights, custom_root='product_highlights')
    file = open('filename', "wb")
    file.write(xml)
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `description_items` to build a dictionary with `description` and `price` information for every product:

```py
product_data = {}
for description_item in description_items:
    product_id = description_item["product_id"]
    product_data[product_id] = description_item
```

Then you can use it in your code like this

```py
highlights = []
for product_id, product_highlight in self.product_highlight_dict.items():
    highlight = vars(product_highlight)
    if product_id in product_data:
        highlight.update(product_data[product_id])
    highlights.append(highlight)
```